# Using variadic template by lambda capture and pass to function's argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2015

```
template<typename FN_, typename ... Arguments>
SuspendThread(FN_&& func, Arguments&& ... args)
{
    auto fut_suspend = Psuspend.get_future();
    std::thread it(
        [fut = std::move(fut_suspend), func, args ...]()
    {
        fut.wait();
        func(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
    });
    task.swap(it);
}
```

I use VS 2015 RC. Now I'm making just simple things.

I want to make func to use args but while template instantiation it's get 
error.

Am I wrong to use variadic template with lambda?

Here is full error:

```
1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2337: 'fut': attribute not found

1>PATH\main.cpp(6): note: see reference to function template
instantiation 
'SuspendThread::SuspendThread<main::<lambda_380b530b324058b12b3b95b6ff957dd6>,int,int>(FN_
&&,int &&,int &&)' being compiled 1         with 1         [ 1  
FN_=main::<lambda_380b530b324058b12b3b95b6ff957dd61         ]

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2337: 'move': attribute not found

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2337: 'func': attribute not found

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2337: 'args': attribute not found

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2143: syntax error: missing ']'
before  '...'

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')'
before  ']'

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';'
before  ']'

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2059: syntax error: ']'

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(29): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';'
before  '{'

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(31): error C2065: 'fut': undeclared
identifier

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(31): error C2228: left of '.wait' must have 
class/struct/union

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(31): note: type is 'unknown-type'

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(33): error C2059: syntax error: ')'

1>PATH\suspendthread.hpp(34): error C2664: 'void 
std::thread::swap(std::thread &) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1
from 'std::thread (__cdecl *)(...)' to 'std::thread &'
```

Comment: I don't see a return type - is that your error?

Comment: could you post the compilation error, whitout it ... it's quite not an easy task to help you!

Comment: Umm... My VS is not english version 
wait plz

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - we need a full example and the compile error.

Comment: @jen6 look at this MCVE -  http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FT6UQzxtJlpLGY8W

Comment: `SuspendThread t([](int a, int b) {cout << a << b << endl; }, 3 ,1);`
I use like this
umm...

Comment: What is the name and version of your compiler?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it's visual studio 2015 rc

Comment: Can you please give us a portion of the program that we can compile to get the same error? Right now this is not enough code for us to see what's wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/jen6/SuspendThread/tree/error
this is error version branch

Comment: The cause of the error is because your compiler doesn't support C++14 init-captures. This is odd because [Visual Studio 2015 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx#C++) is said to support a slew of new C++14 features including init-capture. Maybe you should try reinstalling the compiler.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think that's not a problem.

Comment: https://github.com/jen6/SuspendThread/blob/master/SuspendThread/SuspendThread/SuspendThread.hpp

because it woks well

Comment: I see. Then it's a bug in your compiler. A parameter pack expansion in a capture-list should capture each argument. This works in clang and gcc. I don't know of a work around though.

Comment: omg.. I'll check once again and try to report to ms

Comment: The workaround in this case is to use list initialization for `it` - use `std::thread it{/*lambda*/};`. It looks like that pack expansion makes MSVC want to parse your declaration as a function declaration, and it wants that `[` to be the beginning of an attribute list for the first parameter. This does look like a compiler bug and should be reported.

Comment: Ok thanks It's not my fault! LoL